# Entity Framework Core Computed Property Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I'm working on an ASP.Net Core web application with Entity Framework Core 3.1.
Let's say I have those four entities :

```
public class Project
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }

    public int ProjectTypeId { get; set; }
    public ProjectType ProjectType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProjectScope> ProjectScopes { get; private set; } = new HashSet<ProjectScope>();
}

public class ProjectScope
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public int ScopeId { get; set; }
    public Scope Scope { get; set; }

}

public class Scope
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProjectScope> ProjectScopes { get; private set; } = new HashSet<ProjectScope>();
}

public class ProjectType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a requirement that I need to display at multiple places, and be able to sort on it, on a database level, a project name that is :
All scopes ordered by name + CreationDate + Project type name + Project name

This is how I can achieve it with a computed property :

```
    public string FullName => 
        "[" + ProjectScopes.Select(ps => ps.Scope.Name).OrderBy(s => s).Aggregate((a, b) => a + " - " + b) + "]" +
        " " + CreationDate.ToString("d") +
        " " + ProjectType.Name +
        " " + Name;
```

Of course, it can't be translated by ef core.
I display this property in multiple arrays of my application and I need to be able to order results based on this field.

What is the best way for me to have this computed field?

I need to be able to select and sort on this field, on whichever client that connects to this database. (It can be PowerBI for example)

- A computed column on the database?
- A trigger?
- A user-defined function?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use view model that encapsulates this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[project_scope]'), 'IsTable') = 1
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[project_scope]
GO
IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[project]'), 'IsTable') = 1
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[project]
GO
IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[scope]'), 'IsTable') = 1
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[scope]
GO
IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[project_type]'), 'IsTable') = 1
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[project_type]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[project_type]
(
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[scope]
(
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[project]
(
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   creation_date DATETIMEOFFSET,
   project_type_id INT
)
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[project_scope]
(
   project_id INT NOT NULL,
   scope_id INT NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[project_type]
   (id, name)
VALUES
   (1, 'Type 1')
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[scope]
   (id, name)
VALUES
   (1, 'Scope A')
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[scope]
   (id, name)
VALUES
   (2, 'Scope B')
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[scope]
   (id, name)
VALUES
   (3, 'Scope C')
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[project]
   (id, name, creation_date, project_type_id)
VALUES
   (1, 'Project Avengers', SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), 1)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[project_scope]
   (project_id, scope_id)
VALUES
   (1, 1),
   (1, 2),
   (1, 3)
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[udfGetProjectFullName]', 'FN') IS NOT NULL
   DROP FUNCTION udfGetProjectFullName
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetProjectFullName](@project_id INT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @fullname NVARCHAR(255)

   SELECT @fullname = CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(s.name, ' - ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.name), '] ', p.creation_date, ' ', pt.name, ' ', p.name)
   FROM project AS p
      INNER JOIN project_type AS pt on pt.id = p.project_type_id
      LEFT JOIN project_scope AS ps on ps.project_id = p.id
      LEFT JOIN scope AS s on s.id = ps.scope_id
   WHERE p.id = 1
   GROUP BY p.id, p.name, p.creation_date, pt.name

   RETURN @fullname
END
GO
SELECT id, dbo.udfGetProjectFullName(id) as [full_name]
FROM project
GO
```

Comment: Awesome :) Thank you for your time. It does the trick perfectly.

Comment: That's great, best of luck.

Comment: @GuillaumeLujan could you mark it as answer it's helpful? it will help others to find this issue more easily

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the amount of data, frequency of reads/updates, how often sorting would occur.
Have you considered using SQL View? Has a capacity to be indexed, materialized, etc.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace sqlview
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var dbContext = new EmpDbContext();

            // create db table
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            // create view with "FullName" column as an aggregate like "First Name - Middle Name - Last Name"
            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS View_EmployeeView;");
            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
                @"CREATE VIEW View_EmployeeView AS 
                        SELECT
                            e.Id,
                            e.FirstName + ' - ' + e.MiddleName + ' - '  + e.LastName as FullName
                        FROM Employees e;
            ");

            // insert record
            dbContext.Add(new Employee() { FirstName = "John", MiddleName = "Jack", LastName = "Sugarcoater" });
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // fetch using view
            var employeesFromView = dbContext.EmployeesFromView.ToListAsync().Result;
            foreach (var emp in employeesFromView)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Full name: {emp.FullName}");
            }
        }

        class EmpDbContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
            public DbSet<EmployeeView> EmployeesFromView { get; set; }

            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                    @"YOUR CONNECTION STRING");
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                // configure view
                modelBuilder
                    .Entity<EmployeeView>(eb =>
                    {
                        eb.HasNoKey();
                        eb.ToView("View_EmployeeView");
                    });
            }
        }

        public class Employee
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string MiddleName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }

        public class EmployeeView
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string FullName { get; set; } // will be computed on the SQL side
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello there, 
Since I would like to have this column no only on my web application but available to others clients (PowerBI for example), I am considering SQL views, yes.
unfortunately, I don't know SQL that much, but I'm really good at using Linq.
Could you show me a way to create an SQL View and use it in my ASP.Net Core application with Entity Framework Core ?

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Thank you for your example, unfortunately it matches a very simple case (firstName + lastName) but my case is more complicated. Thanks for pointed it to the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You can have it as a property in the class itself.

Just inform EF to ignore this property by overriding DbContext.OnModelCreating and using EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore method.

Comment: You can also just create an extension method against Project class for FullName, that way you keep the computation separate and not worry about EF also.

Comment: It's a good solution but this column need to be computed on server side. Also, this column will be used by another clients (like PowerBI)

Comment: How are these entities persisted in the database? I assume they are in separate tables. If so, one approach would be to create a UDF and your computed column should use the UDF.  Just wanted to run by another approach - if there is only system responsible for creating those entities (source system) and all other systems (including BI) just consumes the value, why can't you compute the value on client-side and persist the same every time changes are made? If there are multiple systems that can create or modify the values, then this approach won't work.

Comment: Yes, User-Defined function can be a solution. 
Those entities are in separate tables. Multiple clients will be able to read that data. They need to be able to sort on it like any column.
Can you provide an example if possible?

Answer (score -2):

You can use a ViewModel that can encapsulate this and that model can have a property which could evaluate the above.

In my use case, i have used AutoMapper, and created a mapping configuration where i do the transformation as well. Like, i am determining, an user's Active property that i need on the UI based on the EndDate prop from Db.

Using automapper, i am achieving this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Models.ViewModels.User> AsViewModel(this IEnumerable<Models.DataModels.User> userData)
{
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {                
            cfg.CreateMap<Models.DataModels.User, Models.ViewModels.User>()
            .ForMember(vm => vm.Active, d => d.MapFrom(m => !m.EndDate.HasValue))
            .ReverseMap();
        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Models.DataModels.User>, IEnumerable<Models.ViewModels.User>>(userData);
}
```

My Data Model that interacts with the Db via EF is:

```
namespace PM.Models.DataModels
{
    [Table("Users")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue("getdate()")]
        public DateTime Created
        {
            get { return _createdValue == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now : _createdValue; }
            set { _createdValue = value; }
        }
        private DateTime _createdValue;

        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my Viewmodel that i use to interact with my presentation layer:

```
namespace PM.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get { return string.Format($"{LastName}, {FirstName}"); } }
        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Like the other answer pointed out, you can simply use the Model to encap your FullName or in an expanded business use case, you can transform into complex evaluations.

Comment: It's a good solution but this column need to be computed on server side. Also, this column will be used by another clients (like PowerBI)

Comment: This is the server side computing only. And if you wonder that the conversion happening at ViewModel considered as on client side, no, this is/will be done at the server side before returning the data to the consuming client or app / presentation layer.

Comment: To those who down voted, may i please know the reason why? The above is a working sample code, and its up to the individuals to implement their own logic approach in the ViewModel/model classes getter, or in case of complex mapping scenarios, could explore an existing pkgs/tools like automapper than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Unfortunately, in your example of firstName + lastName, Entity Framework Core is obviously able to translate this simple operation to SQL. So yes, in your example the computing is done server side. On my example, the property rely on multiple relationships, and also need to order some of them as part of the name. Entity Framework is not able to translate it to SQL.